# Handlebars if statement doesn't work how it should?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a condition inside my view, I use the same method previously to do this condition and it works normally, but here doesn't for some reason. I'm trying to hide the content from the user if a certain condition is not met, the issue is that even when the condition is false the if statement doesn't hide the content. the condition returns false and I even print the condition alone to see if it was returning correctly but still somehow the if statement decides not to hide the content.

```
<body>

    {{#if votante.estado}}
        
    <div class="pricing-header p-3 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    
          <h1 class="display-4 fw-normal">Puestos disponibles</h1>
        
          <!-- these right here work normally, they show their values-->

          <h4>Bienvenido, {{votante.nombre}} {{votante.apellido}}.</h4>
    
          <p class="fs-5 text-muted">Aqui debes elegir uno de los puestos disponibles para votar.</p>
    
         <!-- I print the value of the condition and it returns false but still it doesn't print the h2 down there -->

          <h3>{{votante.estado}}</h3>

    </div>
    
    {{else}}

    <h2 class="display-4 fw-normal">User inactive.</h2>

    {{/if}}

</body>
```

Comment: what is the value of `votante.estado` when you want that section hidden? or, in other words what is `<h3>{{votante.estado}}</h3>` displaying when it should be hidden

Comment: I would make sure that the value of `votante.estado` is a Boolean and not a String.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue in the least expected way possible. For reference, this is how the code works: I have form to create the "votante", which you could say is a user, that user has a field called "estado" which is status, which could be true or false. Depending on that status I was trying to restrict access to the user to certain parts of the app, think about it like if somebody deactivates your account and you can no longer access to the app.

I was trying to pass the value directly to the render view and it was not working, so I created a switch with the condition votante.estado with two cases, true or false, and depending on that a new variable called estadovotante was created and assigned a new value, if true value is 1 and, if false the value is -1.

after the value of the new variable estadovotante is assigned, then just render the view and pass the value view as estadovotante: estadovotante > 0, that would be true or false in the condition inside the view depending on which is it. Hopefully I was clear enough. This is the code in the javascript behind it:

```
        const votante = elector.dataValues;


    switch(elector.estado){

        case "true":

            estadovotante = 1;


            console.log("valor xd:" + estadovotante);

            res.render("votaciones/elegir-puesto",{votante: votante, estadovotante: estadovotante > 0});

        break;

        case "false":


            estadovotante = -1;

            console.log("valor:" + estadovotante);
            
    
            res.render("votaciones/elegir-puesto",{votante: votante, estadovotante: estadovotante > 0});

        break;

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your own solution the problem is clear.
`elector.estado` contains a **string** not a **boolean**. Therefore, you were doing

```
if("false")
{
    //WRONG, actually true! (truthy)
}
else
{
    //never executed
}
```

So the else part never got executed! Perhaps you have to preprocess `elector.estado` before handing it over to Handlebars, like so

```
elector.estado = JSON.parse(elector.estado); //"true" -> true, "false" -> false;
```